# How to open Protege 4.3 after installing jdk1.8.0_45?

Tags: java-8, protege4

On windows 7 64 bit, I installed protege-4.3.0-304, which I downloaded along with jvm from [here](http://protege.stanford.edu/download/protege/4.3/installanywhere/Web_Installers/InstData/Windows_64bit/VM/install_protege_4.3.exe). And It was working fine.

But once I updated jvm with `jdk1.8.0_45`, I am not able to open protege. It is giving following error:

> G:\protege-4.3.0-304\Protege_4.2>java -server - Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -DentityExpansionLimit=100000000 -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dorg.protege.plugin.dir=plugins -classpath bin/felix.jar;bin/ProtegeLauncher.jar org.protege.osgi.framework.Launcher
>       ERROR: Bundle org.protege.common [1](http://protege.stanford.edu/download/protege/4.3/installanywhere/Web_Installers/InstData/Windows_64bit/VM/install_protege_4.3.exe) Error starting file:/G:/protege-4.3.0-304/Protege_4.2/bundles/org.protege.common.jar 
> (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.protege.common [1](http://protege.stanford.edu/download/protege/4.3/installanywhere/Web_Installers/InstData/Windows_64bit/VM/install_protege_4.3.exe): Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.w3c.dom)(version>=0.0.0)))
>       org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.protege.common [1](http://protege.stanford.edu/download/protege/4.3/installanywhere/Web_Installers/InstData/Windows_64bit/VM/install_protege_4.3.exe): Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.w3c.dom)(version>=0.0.0))

Please somebody help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by correcting path entry into environment variables. When I installed jdk1.8.0_45, it has added path entry of environment variable like "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin". Therefore I renamed the location of JRE according to this path setting. I removed "C:\Program Data\Oracle\Java\javapath" from path variable, which contains three symbolic links to java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe. Due to renaming JRE location, these links were not valid.Moreover I have specified JAVA_HOME to jdk location.

Answer (score 14):

Just to document this for myself and possibly anyone else:

Downgrading Java is NOT required. You only need to replace `bin/felix.jar` with a current version from [felix.apache.org](http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Comment: Confirmed being a fix for a not-starting freshly installed Protege installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when I installed Oracle Java 8 JRE/JDK on my Linux Mint 17 machine. Protege 4.3.0-304 doesn't seem to work with Java 8. I get a bunch of error messages when I try to run Protege with Java 8 as JVM. I found a workaround to fix this issue. The workaround is to force Protege to use a Java 7 JRE when it starts running. To do this, it's simple. I simply modified the Protege launcher script `run.sh` so that it uses the `java` executable of a Java 7 JRE.

**`run.sh` before modifications :**

```
#!/bin/sh

cd `dirname $0`

java -Xmx500M -Xms250M \
     -server \
     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml \
     -DentityExpansionLimit=100000000 \
     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
     -classpath bin/felix.jar:bin/ProtegeLauncher.jar \
     org.protege.osgi.framework.Launcher
```

In my case, I changed `java` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` and I added the line `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` at the beginning. It could be different for you depending on your current configuration.

**`run.sh` after modifications :**

```
#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

cd `dirname $0`

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xmx500M -Xms250M \
     -server \
     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml \
     -DentityExpansionLimit=100000000 \
     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
     -classpath bin/felix.jar:bin/ProtegeLauncher.jar \
     org.protege.osgi.framework.Launcher
```

If you don't have OpenJDK 7 already installed, you could install it via your distro repos (this could change the default JVM back to Java 7 after installing. Correct this with `sudo update-alternatives --config java`) or you could try to use the [Oracle Java 7 JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jre-7u80-oth-JPR) and put the `jre1.7.0_80` folder somewhere so the Protege launcher script can use the `java` executable inside it. I don't know about the Protege launcher executable on Windows, but I guess it's something similar and this solution could work for Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem with my Windows 8, java 8.
the problem has been resolved by changing the `filix.jar` file, in `G:\Program Files\Protege_4.3\bin"`, By a new one copied from a `protége 5.0` directory.
it should be noted that the file  `filix.jar` is named `"org.apache.felix.main.jar"` in version 5, you can only rename it and it work correctly.